# jq - assert exactly 1 element reutrned

Tags: jq

I use the following jq snippet to extract a key out of an array of values:

```
jq '[.[].refreshToken | select(. != null)] | unique]'
```

How can I assert that only 1 element was returned? If more than 1 element found in resulting array I want a non 0 status code returned / otherwise resulting JSON array containing 1 element.

```json
   [{
      "tokenType":"Bearer",
      "expiresIn":3599,
      "expiresOn":"2021-09-28 17:41:15.929902",
      "resource":"https://management.core.windows.net/",      
      "accessToken":"lkZXIuZ2mn_A",
      "refreshToken":"0.AYIAGNEIQ9HtAEOq4v1k",
      "oid":"0000-ea77-4abe-961b-0000",
      "userId":"john.doe@yahoo.com",
      "isMRRT":true,
      "_clientId":"0000-0000-0000-0000",
      "_authority":"https://login.microsoftonline.com/common"
   }]
```

Answer (score 0):

One can make the `jq` utility exit with an exit-status corresponding to the last evaluated value, using its `--exit-status` (or `-e`) command-line option.

```bsh
jq -r -e '[.[] | select(.refreshToken != null)] | unique | if length == 1 then .[].refreshToken else empty end' file
```

If the last statement evaluated in the expression above is true, non-empty, non-null, the exit status of `jq` will be zero; otherwise, it will be non-zero.

The comments revealed that what's sought is the `refreshToken` data, but only if it's unique.  You could do this with

```bsh
jq -r -e '[.[].refreshToken // empty] | unique | if length == 1 then .[] else empty end' file
```

Comment: I tried using the following but it always returns 0: `jq -e -r '([.[].refreshToken | select(. != null)] | unique) as $r | if $r | length == 1 then $r | .[] else "" end'`

However using `jq -e -r '([.[].refreshToken | select(. != null)] | unique) as $r | if $r | length == 1 then $r | .[] else null end'` works as expected (note the `null`)

Comment: @SoonGuy Why do you complicate it so much? You should be able to do just `jq -e '[ .[].refreshToken | select(. != null) ] | unique | length == 1' file.json`, but it's difficult to say for sure because you are not showing the document that you work with.

Comment: because I need the resulting JSON returned when `length == 1`

Comment: @SoonGuy See updated answer.

Comment: I need only the matched JSON (hence `$r`) returned. When jq expression `true` return only the 1 `refreshToken` in raw format (no quotes). otherwise return non-0 exit code. The exit code tells my program if a refreshToken was returned to stdout

Comment: @SoonGuy If you want to clarify your question, do so by editing it.

Answer (score -1):

Solved: `jq -r '([.[].refreshToken | select(. != null)] | unique) as $r | if $r | length == 1 then $r | .[] else null end'`

Comment: I assume it depends on what the document looks like.